# No printer drivers installed on OS x el capitan

Tags: macos, drivers, printer

I'm trying to install printers shared by an Ubuntu CUPS machine on an El Capitan Mac.

According to Apple and HP's website, it should 'just work' - drivers should be provided through the OS. However when I go to add a printer, select the HP D1500 listed (discovered via bonjour), it does not load any HP drivers - just generic postscript.

Ditto with a Brother printer.

Perhaps the Mac can't determine the model / make from Bonjour? But when I go to the list of drivers it's tiny and doesn't contain any HP (or Brother) ones? I searched on printer drivers in the Software store (or whatever it's called in mac land) - nothing useful comes up.

With the Brother I've downloaded drivers direct from their site, but this seems a really 90s way of doing things. **Is there a way to get El Capitan to do it itself?** I tried using the CUPS web interface but it appears that Apple in their wisdom broke that some time ago and you can no longer authenticate without enabling root, something that I think has just got harder in the Yosemite - El Capitan update.

Comment: I have a Brother MFP (model J6420) and El Capitan. I d/l'd the driver from the Brother website, installed it and found the driver when I setup the printer in SysPref. It may seem like "a really 90s way" but I don't argue with what works. BTW, I think the driver only mentioned OSX 10.9 or 10.10. Just get the latest driver...

Comment: Fair enough for brother, uncommon, but HP should have integrated installation according to Apple and HP, and it's not there.

Comment: Believe me, if I had a dollar for every time I thought about what HP *should do* with products, I'd be a rich man. There driver support is user hostile.